# Extract rows from dataframe containing each label

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

In the example `dataframe` shown below, I have 5 labels (`class_name`).  There are 31 files (31 rows) in all to work with...

I am attempting to extract 80% (can be variable) of the rows (= 24 rows (integer)).  However, I wanted to ensure that I extract at least 1 row from each `class_name`

For my attempt, I can only do this manually.  This approach gets tedious as the `class_name` is much more that 10.  Can you assist me in extracting the correct % rows to contain at least 1 entry from each label (`class_name`).

Here is my attempt:

```
import math
import pandas as pd

base_path = 'G:/PandasFileSeperation'
original_df = pd.read_csv(f'{base_path}/Book2.csv')

original_df = original_df.astype(str)
length = original_df.class_name.count()
length

# Get number of groups
dfg = original_df.groupby('class_name')
numgroups = dfg.ngroups
numgroups

# Get the sizes of each group
group_size =  original_df.groupby('class_name').size()

# Get length of original dataframe
Total_dataset_size = len(original_df)

# Get number of Training samples
TrainPercent = 0.80

Train_size = int(Total_dataset_size * TrainPercent)
Train_size

# How can I change this to automatically change the label size length to give at least 1 row from each class?
Label_0_size = 5
Label_1_size = 3
Label_2_size = 7
Label_3_size = 7
Label_4_size = 2

# Training Dataset
label_percent = { 'pigs' : Label_0_size, 'goats' : Label_1_size, 'chickens' : Label_2_size, 'hens' : Label_3_size, 'sheep' : Label_4_size}

flag = True
for label, num_rows in label_percent.items():
  
  row_num = num_rows
  
  if label == 'pigs':
    row_num0 = Label_0_size
    df = original_df[original_df['class_name'] == label]
    df = df.head(row_num0)

  elif label == 'goats':
    row_num2 = Label_1_size
    df = original_df[original_df['class_name'] == label]
    df = df.head(row_num1)
    
    
  elif label == 'chickens':
    row_num2 = Label_2_size
    df = original_df[original_df['class_name'] == label]
    df = df.head(row_num2)
    
  elif label == 'hens':
    row_num3 = Label_3_size
    df = original_df[original_df['class_name'] == label]
    df = df.head(row_num3)
    
  else:
    row_num4 = Label_4_size
    df = original_df[original_df['class_name'] == label]
    df = df.head(row_num4)

  if flag == True:
    Train_df = df
    flag = False
  else:
    Train_df = pd.concat([Train_df, df])

Train_df.to_csv(f'{base_path}/Train_df.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

###### Dataframe:

| slice_file_name | fsID | start | end | salience | fold | classID | class_name | original_class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-1000020520400.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 1 | pigs |  |
| 1-100004024000001.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 1 | pigs |  |
| 1-10000406050001.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 1 | pigs |  |
| 1-1000050120400.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 1 | pigs |  |
| 1-1000050320400.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 1 | pigs |  |
| 1-1000050520400.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2 | goats |  |
| 1-10000601400001000.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2 | goats |  |
| 1-1000060340000.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2 | goats |  |
| 1-100006070500.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 3 | chickens |  |
| 1-100007020800.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 3 | chickens |  |
| 1-100007024000001.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 3 | chickens |  |
| 1-1000070320400.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 3 | chickens |  |
| 1-100007050800.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 3 | chickens |  |
| 1-100007064000001.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 3 | chickens |  |
| 1-100010620400.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 3 | chickens |  |
| 1-100040620400.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 3 | chickens |  |
| 1-10006020500.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 3 | chickens |  |
| 1-10006030500.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 3 | chickens |  |
| 1-100060520400.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 4 | hens |  |
| 1-10007020500.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 4 | hens |  |
| 2-100070420400.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 4 | hens |  |
| 2-100070540000.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 4 | hens |  |
| 2-1313131313004.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 4 | hens |  |
| 2-1313131313043.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 4 | hens |  |
| 2-1313131313044.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 5 | sheep |  |
| 2-150002020500.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 5 | sheep |  |
| 2-150002060800.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 5 | sheep |  |
| 2-150004022040001.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 5 | sheep |  |
| 2-15000406050001.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 5 | sheep |  |
| 2-150006014000001.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 5 | sheep |  |
| 2-150006024000001.wav |  |  |  |  | 1 | 5 | sheep |  |

As a starting, can we do a `forloop` and start with each class = 1 then increment each class, checking the sum after each iteration until the total classes = `Train_size`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help. Sample the dataframe twice: Once using `groupby` to sample one row for each name, then sample from the rest of the dataframe randomly to complete the 80% training set.

```py
TrainPercent = 0.8
# sample one row for each class_name (5 rows)
one_each = df.groupby('class_name').sample(n=1)
# from the rest of the rows, sample int(0.8*len(df))-len(one_each) number of rows (19 rows)
rest = df.loc[~df.index.isin(one_each.index)].sample(n=int(TrainPercent*len(df))-len(one_each))
# concatenate the two
res = pd.concat([one_each, rest])
```